# Variable value has to pass in the Databricks direct sql query instead of spark.sql(""" """)

Tags: databricks

In the databricks notebook, I have written the query

%sql
set four_date='2021-09-16';
select * from df2_many where four_date='{​​​​​​​{​​​​​​​four_date}​​​​​​​}​​​​'

Its not working, please advise that how to apply in the direct query instead of spark.sql("""  """)

Note: dont use $ its asking value in the text box, please confirm if there is any other alternative solution
how to apply the variable values which is to manipulate in the direct query at the Databricks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794549/how-can-i-access-python-variable-in-spark-sql/68962278#68962278

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Databricks Notebook, you will need to use Widgets:

https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html

```
CREATE WIDGET DATE four_date DEFAULT "2021-09-16"

SELECT * FROM df2_many WHERE four_date=getArgument("four_date")​​​​
```