# How to create a variable from a SQL statement's output in Databricks

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I would like to create a variable that I can use later in multiple sql queries within the same notebook. The variable itself is simply an integer output from a sql statement such as:

```
    select count(people) from persons_table;
```

Then in subsequent sql command cells, I would simply call the variable in calculations such as:

```
    select (count(cars) / $variable) as car_rate from table_x;
```

The only variables I've used in Databricks have been simple widgets from a Python script (dbutils.widgets.text('name','value')).

I already have an alternative, where I have a temp table with the output, but would rather use a variable if this is possible.

Comment: `table_x` is the variable, or constant?

Comment: table_x is a constant table.

Comment: why not use the common table expressions? https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-cte.html

Comment: I can, but was wondering if a variable is an option. I have about 400 union'd queries, so I could wrap it and then use a CTE I guess.

Comment: it's possible to pass from Python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794549/how-can-i-access-python-variable-in-spark-sql/68962278#68962278), another possibility is to create a widget and refer to it, but I'm not sure about efficiency

Answer (score 1):

I found this while looking for the same problem.  As your qustion isn't answered I'll put the one I found for others.  I'm not sure it is the best, but it works.

Use a python notebook.

Then you can use python variables.

```
peopleCount = spark.sql("select count(people) from persons_table").collect()[0][0]
```

The spark.sql reads the sql into a pyspark dataframe, if you just sent the SQL the variable would be a dataframe object.  The collect reads the result from the dataframe into the variable.  The [0][0] is the "offset" but you only need to worry about that if you have more than one column or row.

Then in the next cell

```
%sql 

select (count(cars) / '$peopleCount') as car_rate from table_x;
```

The %sql tells databricks this is a SQL cell and the variable needs to be in quotes with a $