# Unable to share across dataframe in same notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

If i am using both Scala and python in same notebook in databricks, how spark session would create two session or single session?

If it is different session for Scala and python, how tempview is sharing across them? Eventhough we are not able to share variables among them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work with the same Spark JVM instance defined on the cluster level. And because of this, temp view defined in one language will be visible from another cell that uses different language - that's common way of sharing datasets between different languages.  Another way to pass data between languages is to use `spark.conf.set` & `spark.conf.get` - but it should be limited to the small amounts of data.

P.S. Look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794549/how-can-i-access-python-variable-in-spark-sql/68962278#68962278) that shows how to share variables between Pytnon & SQL.

Comment: No, there will be a single Spark Session per cluster

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott
Can you please answer for below question
1.Even though if we are using same notebook for python and Scala, will spark session create for both language individually? (why I am asking, because it is not sharable right?)
2. if it is create individually, what is the difference between global cluster level spark session and Notebook Level Session?

Comment: All languages are sharing the same JVM SparkSession, that are wrapped into language-specific objects