# Spark SQL - Replace schema/table based on input parameters

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I have a simple PySpark code on Databricks which reads the data from a bucket, few minor transformations and writes to delta table.

Currently following below steps. I have hardcoded catalog/schema/table names for now. I need to dynamically replace catalog/schema/table based on parameters. With PySpark, we can easily replace values, is there anyway we can replace values for <catalog_name>.<schema_name>.<table_name> used in final SQL insert, based on input parameters?

1. Read input data and create dataframe
2. basic transformation
3. create temp table from dataframe using createOrReplaceTempView()
4. write to delta table as below

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true") .schema(schema_name).csv(source_path)

df.createOrReplaceTempView(temp_table)

# how can we replace the names based on input parameter/variable
insert into <"name_of_catalog">.<"name_of_schema">.<"name_of_table">
select * from temp_table;
```

Comment: other than replacing in python, then running resultant string as spark.sql(""), do we any other options?

Comment: You try creating the widgets again and use them directly in the spark-sql ? Refer to this [link](https://docs.databricks.com/en/notebooks/widgets.html#using-widget-values-in-spark-sql)

Comment: This works for me - `CREATE WIDGET TEXT database_name DEFAULT "default";
SHOW TABLES IN ${database_name}` - you can try something similar I guess...

Comment: if we need to using spark without Databricks specific custom features, is there any way we could achieve this?

Comment: mmm, Would you mind looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019868/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-queries) and see if it helps ? I have not tried it, but seems very reliable to work...

Comment: Did it help ? if so please consider adding an answer linking to that answer so that others will also find it useful...

Comment: I didnot get a chance to try out yet, but looking at the doc you have shared, both the options should work.